# Retrieve realtime data from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I have a flutter project set up to receive moisture sensor data from firebase. I am uploading data to firebase and trying to retrieve it on my app but it only retrieves data after some time. Moreover, the value is null till then. And also, when changed there is no change in data on the app. How do I get the data so that it shows data from the moment I start the app and changes when data on the firebase updates? Here is my code.

```
  double moistureData;

  @override
  bool _isLoading = false;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseReference.child('Data').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      int moisture = snapshot.value['Moisture'];
      moistureData = moisture.toDouble();
      print(moisture);
      setState(() {
        if (moistureData != null) {
        _isLoading = true;
        }
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Moisture'),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: databaseReference.child('Data').child('Moisture').onValue,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('$moistureData'),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('Refresh'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              databaseReference
                                  .child('Data')
                                  .once()
                                  .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                int moisture = snapshot.value['Moisture'];
                                moistureData = moisture.toDouble();
                              });
                            });
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen for both the current value and updates, you need to observe one of the `on...` stream properties of the [query object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query-class.html). The closest to your current code is `onValue` stream.

An example from the [FlutterFire example app](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart#L69):

> ```
> _counterRef.onValue.listen((Event event) {
>   setState(() {
>     _error = null;
>     _counter = event.snapshot.value ?? 0;
>   });
> }
> ```

So you see that this also uses the `setState(...)` that [@satish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58901491/209103) explains.

Comment: Thank you very much for your consult. I did manage to make it work by following the example. Cheers.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't have enough reputations to make a visible change. I did accepted the answer. Thank you for your time and suggestion. I was on a deadline and managed to make it work at last hour.

Comment: To accept my answer, you have to click the check mark. It may take some time before that is enable though.

Answer (score 1):

of course, it takes some time to load data from firebase, create one bool variable and set it false.

```
double moistureData;
bool _isLoading=false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseReference.child('Data').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      final int moisture = snapshot.value['Moisture'];
      moistureData=moisture.toDouble();
      print(moisture);
    setState((){
    if(moistureData!=null)
     _isLoading=true;
      });
    });
  }
```

And inside your widget pass, circular progress indicator or an empty container when _isLoading is false. when it's true called your widget inside else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That does solve the issue of loading although it shows error screen for a while. But that still doesn't refresh the data. I am open to any suggestions regarding real time data refresh. I have edited rest of my code above.

Comment: You already using StreamBuilder, and when you change anything to firebase it automatic update widget,

Comment: But somehow it didnot. So I used onValue(listen) event to listen to changes and update my values from the changes. And it worked. To overcome delay between app and firebase database, I used 5sec delay to send sensor data and it works like a charm. I forgot to dispose the streamsubscription, but that's taken care of as well. Thank you for your support and suggestion.

Comment: Hi, Still you are struggling? @ZeroLive

Comment: I managed to make it work but I am open to suggestions. Right now I am using query object onValue to check for the event changes storing changes on a variable in setstate  and using that variable to display data on textfield.